# Hover happening beyond the width of the element

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

When I hover over the hyperlink, it goes beyond the link text.

The jsFiddle link is : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kcqvfLv/)

Seems it's taking width of the `<div>` and hence appearing throughout the `<div>` element.

Here is the HTML (using foundation):

```
<div class="container row">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="logo" class="large-3 columns">
            <span>My Bank ,too Big</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

How do I solve this? I cannot alter the foundation classes applied here. 
Is this happening due to the `<span>` element?

I tried to reduce the `<span>` width but no changes in the behavior was observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have the `div` within `a` tag. All `div` tags are block elements by default and so would take the entire available width whereas an `a` tag is inline by default and would only take whatever is required. It would be fixed if you move the `a` inside the `div` tag like in the below snippet.

```css
.row.container {
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.row.container {
  position: relative;
}
.row.container:after,
.row.container:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.large-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
#logo {
  margin: 46px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <div id="logo" class="large-3 columns">
    <a href="#">
      <span>My Bank ,too Big</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add this to your `#logo` rule:

```
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

This preserves the entire `<div>` element as the clickable area, instead of just that of the `<span>`, all the while keeping the `<div>` element width consistent with the text.

Try out the code below:

```css
.row.container {
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.row.container {
  position: relative;
}
.row.container:after,
.row.container:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.large-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
#logo {
  margin: 46px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 46px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="logo" class="large-3 columns">
      <span>My Bank ,too Big</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `#logo` width to `auto` and then make the anchor `inline-block`.

Alternately set the `#logo` to `display: inline-block` or `inline`.  The problem arises when you put a block element `<div>` inside an inline element `<a>`.

```css
.row.container {
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.row.container {
  position: relative;
}
row.container:after,
.row.container:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.large-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
header #logo {
  margin: 46px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 46px;
}
#logo {
  width: auto;
}
.row.container a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="logo" class="large-3 columns">
      <span>My Bank ,too Big</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```